# SEO-URL Multistore problem, website-url is fine, but product-url stays the same

Tags: multistore, url, seo

I have a multistore website, but the seo is not working totally fine
Like the title says: The website-url is fine, but product-url stays the same. But the product-url should be different for every store.
In the .phtml is the follwing code:

```
<?php foreach ($block->getUrls() as $url): ?>
    <link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo $url['href'] ?>" hrefLang="<?php echo $url['hrefLang'] ?>"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And in the .php the code is:

```
foreach ($this->getAllStore() as $store) {
        $arr[] = [
            'href'     => str_replace($this->getStoreBaseUrl(), $store->getBaseUrl(), $this->getCanonicalUrl()),
            'hrefLang' => $this->setHreflang($store->getId())
        ];
```

The wrong output is now:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://testing.xxx.de/victor-blue.html" hrefLang="de-DE"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.xxx.nl/victor-blue.html" hrefLang="x-default"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://testing.xxx.be/victor-blue.html" hrefLang="nl-BE"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://testing.xxx.fr/victor-blue.html" hrefLang="fr-FR"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://testing.xxx.com/victor-blue.html" hrefLang="en-GB"/>
```

But I want the correct url from the correct store (the color is different as below):

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://testing.xxx.de/victor-blue.html" hrefLang="de-DE"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.xxx.nl/victor-blauw.html" hrefLang="x-default"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://testing.xxx.be/victor-turkoois.html" hrefLang="nl-BE"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://testing.xxx.fr/victor-blue.html" hrefLang="fr-FR"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://testing.xxx.com/victor-bluw.html" hrefLang="en-GB"/>
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your getCanonicalUrl() function. Please check the return data in this function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but what should be different in the code: public function getCanonicalUrl()
 {

  $url = $this->getCurrentUrl();

  if ($this->helperData->getDuplicateConfig('https_canonical')) {
   $url = str_replace('http:', 'https:', $url);
  }

  if ($this->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'catalogsearch') {
   $position = strrpos($url, "catalogsearch");
   $url      = substr($url, 0, $position + 14);
  }

  return $url;
 }